# C++ Boost Library - trying to get proper format of my property tree

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am trying to write Json using property tree. This is what I have tried:

```
boost::property_tree::propTree propTree1, propTree2, propTree3, propTree4, propTree5, propTree6, propTree7, propTree8, propTree9, propTree10;


propTree1.put( "a", "" );
propTree1.put( "b", "" );
propTree1.put( "c", "" );
propTree2.push_back(std::make_pair("", propTree1)); 

propTree3.put("l", "");
propTree3.put("m", "");
propTree4.push_back(std::make_pair("", propTree3));
propTree1.add_child("Msg", propTree4);

propTree5.put("r", "");
propTree5.put("s", "");
propTree6.push_back(std::make_pair("", propTree5));

propTree1.add_child("Msg1", propTree6);
propTree1.add_child("Msg2", propTree8);

propTree9.put("t", "");
propTree9.put("u", "");
propTree10.push_back(std::make_pair("", propTree9));
propTree1.add_child("Msg3", propTree10);

boost::property_tree::write_json( "OUTPUT", propTree1 );
```

**The Output I am getting is below:**

```
{
"a": "",
"b": "",
"Msg": [
    {
        "l": "",
        "m": ""
    }
],
"Msg1": [
    {
        "r": "",
        "s": ""
    }
],
"Msg2": "",
"Msg3": [
    {
        "t": "",
        "u": ""
    }
]
```

}

**Expected output is below: (Commented are the questions)**

```
{  "Msg0":{     //Missing in my output
"a": "",
"b": "",
"Msg": [
    {
        "l": "",
        "m": ""
    }
],
"Msg1": [
    {
        "r": "",
        "s": "",
    "abc": [    // Missing this "abc" array within Msg1 array
    "note1", //Output with values (no keys like "r" & "s")
    "note2",  // Can we pass setlist/stringstream in "abc" array?
    "note3",
    ]
    }
],
"Msg2": "",
"Msg3": [
    {
        "t": "",
        "u": ""
    }
]
```

} 
}

1) I am not able to get the format of JSON which is mentioned above. Please check the comments.

2) How should I add string/stringstream/setofnames in "abc" array? Which data type can be passed here and how to achieve that?

3) Also is there any efficient way of doing the above work?

Can anyone help me with the above 3 questions? Thanks.